# No device available in debugview firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

i have trying to use debugview in firebase but it is unable to detect my device

i tried the answer -->

1. [DebugView no devices available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138152/debugview-no-devices-available)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44047095/12553303

what i did is to enable debugging is `C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myprojectname`

though it shows no error it also runs the code/project

but it is still showing no device found

need help thanks

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the adb can be buggy. So first run ```adb kill-server ``` then ```adb start-server```. After this ```adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myprojectname``` . Run the application in ```Debug``` mode.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the emulator to work but I managed to get my physical device working with DebugView.

My issue with this was that I had my device connected over wifi (following this guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi), and running `adb devices` only listed the emulator, not my physical device.

After re-connecting through usb (following method 1 of the same guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended), and having my physical device listed with `adb devices` I ran `adb -d shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>` and my device was finally recognized by DebugView

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I got the emulator to work.  I tried using the adb command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.myapp.android.debug
```

Did not work.  I then went into Settings -> About emulated device -> Build number and clicked it until I got Developer options turned on.  Went back to firebase and viola it worked for the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

1- disconnect the device and turn off developer options
2- change the USB cable and reconnect the device
3- Turn on developer options, USB Debugging and Stay awake options
4- Run the following commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

You'll find your device listed
Worked for me