# My application is connected to the firebase analytics but no user is shown online

Tags: android

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: It takes some time ...

Comment: Like @ram said it takes some time for Analytics to show up in Firebase. If you want to see if everything is logged correctly you should try the [debug view](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) which is instant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It takes some time for displaying the stats in firebase, if you want to see your stats immediately, you can use the debug view

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: still not working.Is there any thing else i should do in my project or what ? firstly it was showing user but after adding all functionality it didn't .plz help me out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769236/firebase-analytics-debug-view-does-not-show-anything - refer this

Comment: i did try but no result :(