# Resources$NotFoundException with include-dynamic navigation graph

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, dynamic-feature-module

I have a dynamic feature module with it's own nested navigation graph. I also have a dynamic feature module that's just a single fragment. If you have a dynamic feature module with it's own navigation graph, I understand you need to use the **include-dynamic** tag. When I build the app and deploy the app to the Play Store for internal testing, the dynamic modules download correctly. However If I and building/running locally - the app crashes when I try and navigate to the dynamic feature module that contains the navigation graph. I thought that everything was bundled when running locally? Is there something I'm missing?

The error I get is `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: com.xyz.app_name.two:navigation/two_navigation`

**main_navigation_graph**

```
<!-- this works locally. module does not contain a nav graph -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/OneFragment"
    android:name="com.xyz.app_name.one.OneFragment"
    android:label="{nickname}"
    app:moduleName="one"
    tools:layout="@layout/one_fragment">
    <argument
        android:name="nickname"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>

<!-- this doesn't work locally -->
<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/two_graph"
    app:graphPackage="com.xyz.app_name.two"
    app:graphResName="two_navigation"
    app:moduleName="two" />
```

**feature_two_graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/two_graph"
    app:moduleName="two"
    app:startDestination="@id/twoFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/twoFragment"
        android:name="com.xyz.app_name.two.TwoFragment"
        android:label="{nickname}"
        tools:layout="@layout/two_fragment">
        <argument
            android:name="nickname"
            app:argType="string" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_twoFragment_to_dialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/dialogFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialogFragment"
        android:name="com.xyz.app_name.two.ui.DialogFragment"
        android:label="bottom_sheet"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem.

When trying to add a dynamic-feature graph as destination, using include-dynamic as follow:

```
<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/nestedMyfeatureGraph"
    app:graphPackage="com.mycompany.myapp.mydynamicfeature"
    app:graphResName="nav_graph_feature"
    app:moduleName="mydynamicfeature"
    />
```

one should keep in mind that `app:graphPackage` is supposed to reference the dynamic-feature's *applicationId* (I know, [it's confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366756/what-is-the-difference-between-changing-package-name-vs-applicationid)). If you have any custom gradle script adding suffix to *applicationId* or stuff like that, then referencing the graph will fail.

It probably only worked for you on playstore because I guess your script only adds suffix for non-prodRelease build types, which is a common pattern.

So, to fix the problem I had to replace

```
    app:graphPackage="com.mycompany.myapp.mydynamicfeature"
```

with

```
    app:graphPackage="${applicationId}.mydynamicfeature"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do! It never even crossed my mind - I have build types for dev, qa, and prod. Prod keeps the applicationId the same as the package name, but dev and qa append '.dev' and '.qa' respectfully. Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: It's indeed not easy to realize where the problem is, debugging is not very useful in this case, unless you suspect the appId suffix thing and breakpoint & evaluate different values of graphName in resources.getIdentifier(..)

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work

Comment: For me also it is not working. My dynamic feature module's name is "featuretest". My base module has many build flavors with applicationId suffix. I have not added any suffix in my dynamic feature build.gradle file. When I am specifying app:graphPackage="${applicationId}.featuretest", it is working when I am directly running it from the AS (basically installing apk) but when I am creating a release build it is crashing after downloading the module.

@Oussaki - You found any solution to this?

Comment: @Code-Warrior what happens if you disable obfuscation in release (just for debugging purpose) ?

Comment: @AchrafAmil - I even tried the debug build which does not obfuscate. Even after that I am getting same exception.

Comment: @AchrafAmil - I have asked a new question with all the details there. Have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107523/app-is-not-able-to-find-dynamicfeature-navigation-graph-getting-resourcesnotfo

Comment: @AchrafAmil - I was able to resolve the issue. Details are here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107523/app-is-not-able-to-find-dynamicfeature-navigation-graph-getting-resourcesnotfo/71126287#71126287