# App is not able to find DynamicFeature navigation graph. Getting Resources$NotFoundException for the navigation graph

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature, android-app-bundle

I am using Android's Dynamic delivery for one of my feature. I have separated the code for the feature. I am also using the Navigation component in my project.

I can see dynamicfeature being downloaded from the progress bar and after downloading I am using Navigation component to navigate to Fragment2.

However, when I am trying to navigate from Fragment1 which is in my "app" to Fragment2 which is in my "dynamicfeature" I am getting below exception.

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: com.sample.sample.debug.dynamicfeature:navigation/dynamic_feature_nav
   at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.replaceWithIncludedNav(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:95)
   at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.navigate(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:79)
   at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.navigate(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:40)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:935)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:868)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:854)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1107)
   at com.compass.corelibrary.extensions.NavControllerExtensionsKt.navigateSafeSource(NavControllerExtensions.kt:18)
```

My app's build.gradle file is like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.heapanalytics.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.compass.jacoco.jacoco-android'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

ext.versionMajor = 2
ext.versionMinor = 35
ext.versionPatch = 0
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 21

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.sample"
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.sample.SampleAndroidJUnitRunner"
        ext {
            heapEnabled = true
            heapAutoInit = true
            heapEnvId = HEAP_KEY_GAMMA
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        beta {
            keyAlias "circleci-beta-key-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
            storeFile file("circleci-beta-key.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/kotlinx-serialization-runtime.kotlin_module'
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        debugFlavor {
            getIsDefault().set(true)
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain_staging",
                    auth0Scheme: "sample",
                    facebookLoginProtocolScheme: "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_staging",
                    facebookAppId: "@string/facebook_app_id_staging",
                    facebookProvider: "@string/facebook_provider_staging"
            ]

        }
        alphaFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain_staging",
                    auth0Scheme: "sample",
                    facebookLoginProtocolScheme: "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_staging",
                    facebookAppId: "@string/facebook_app_id_staging",
                    facebookProvider: "@string/facebook_provider_staging"
            ]
        }
        betaFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain_staging",
                    auth0Scheme: "sample",
                    facebookLoginProtocolScheme: "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_staging",
                    facebookAppId: "@string/facebook_app_id_staging",
                    facebookProvider: "@string/facebook_provider_staging"
            ]
        }
        rcFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".rc"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain_staging",
                    auth0Scheme: "sample",
                    facebookLoginProtocolScheme: "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_staging",
                    facebookAppId: "@string/facebook_app_id_staging",
                    facebookProvider: "@string/facebook_provider_staging"
            ]
        }
        playStoreFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain_prod",
                    auth0Scheme: "compass",
                    facebookLoginProtocolScheme: "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_prod",
                    facebookAppId: "@string/facebook_app_id_prod",
                    facebookProvider: "@string/facebook_provider_prod"
            ]
            ext.heapEnvId = HEAP_KEY_PRODUCTION
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            getIsDefault().set(true)
            debuggable true
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LEAK_CANARY", enableLeakCanary
            testCoverageEnabled false
            FirebasePerformance {
                instrumentationEnabled false
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            productFlavors.alphaFlavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
            productFlavors.betaFlavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
            productFlavors.rcFlavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            // Added to ensure timezone is America/New_York for testing purposes
            all{
                jvmArgs '-Duser.timezone=America/New_York'
                systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.url', 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2'

            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest { java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/kotlin'] }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.5'
    }
    dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicfeature']

    preBuild.dependsOn ktlintFormat
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //All the dependencies are here.
}
```

My Dynamic Feature build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            getIsDefault().set(true)
            debuggable true
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
        release {
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        debugFlavor {
            getIsDefault().set(true)
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
        alphaFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
        betaFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
        rcFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
        playStoreFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            matchingFallbacks = ["release", "debug"]
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
}
```

I am navigating to **Fragment2** which is in "dynamicfeature" from **Fragment1** which is in "app". Fragment1 is hosted by **MainActivity** which is in "app".

My app's navigation graph has entry as

```
<include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/me_dynamic_feature"
        app:moduleName="dynamicfeature"
        app:graphResName="dynamic_feature_nav"
        app:graphPackage="${applicationId}.dynamicfeature" />
```

Comment: So which part of the `com.sample.sample.debug.dynamicfeature:navigation/dynamic_feature_nav` that it is looking for is wrong? Is it the package name or do you not have an XML file at `res/navigation/dynamic_feature_nav.xml` in your feature module?

Comment: @ianhanniballake - I can see that dynamicfeature is being downloaded. After downloading I am navigating to Fragment2 using Navigation component. 
navigation file is present in dynamicfeature navigation folder. In my app's build.gradle I have applicationIdSuffix for each product flavor. 

Application id is com.sample.sample
Package name for main app is com.sample.sample
Package name for dynamicfeature module is com.sample.sample.dynamicfeature

One thing which I observed is when I host my Fragment2 in an Activity and try to open the activity from Fragment1, then everything works fine.

Comment: It seems like `${applicationId}.dynamicfeature` isn't the right thing to put in there if that isn't actually the package name of your dynamic feature module. Have you tried putting in the correct package name there?

Comment: @ianhanniballake - I tried putting app:graphPackage="com.sample.sample.dynamicfeature" but it is not working. Now it is not even downloading the dynamic feature module. I got the idea of putting applicationId from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122383/resourcesnotfoundexception-with-include-dynamic-navigation-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. Apparently, if you use `<include-dynamic>` tag for navigating into the dynamic feature module. You have to specify `ProgressFragment` which extends `AbstractProgressFragment` and specify it as `app:progressDestination`.

Also since Fragment1 is in base app, which is hosted by activity in base app. We need to override `attachBaseContext` method in this activity too like below. This will fix the case where same exception was occurring at the subsequent launch.

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
}
```

Comment: As documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#enable_splitcompat